# Android global key event

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a USB thermocouple device that starts/stops by holding 'Num Lock' key for 3 seconds. It was designed for MS Windows OS. It will register as a keyboard/mouse composite device if plugged in to Android devices (with USB OTG adapter). On MS Windows OS I can start/stop device by sending global keystrokes. Android does not allow me to send global keystrokes. Is there a way to simulate a global keyevent or send a keyevent to the USB device?